Existence of some point $ t' \in [0,b] \xrightarrow{\gamma} U_0 \subsetneq U$ ( unit speed radial geodesic ) satisfying certain property.
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian $n$-manifold. $p\in M$. Let $U$ be a normal neighborhood of $p$, and $r$ be the radial distance function on  $U$ ( C.f. Def. : John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifold, p.158 ). Let $U_0 := \{q \in U : r(q) < \pi R \}$ be a proper subset of $U$ so that there exists $q \in U-U_0$. Let $\gamma : [0,b] \to U$ be the unit speed radial geodesic from $p$ to $q$.
Then, there exists $t' \in  [0,b]$ with $q':=\gamma(t')$ such that $\pi R = \operatorname{dist}(p,q')=r(q'):= r(\gamma(t'))=t'$ ( $\because \gamma$ is unit speed radial geodesic ) and $\gamma([0,t')) \subseteq U_0$?  I think that it seems true by drawing picture of $U_0$
and $U$, and I don't know how can we choose such $t'$ more explicitly. I think that we may use the concept of infimum or supremum but still don't know how to define $t'$ concretely.
This question originates from my answer for Proof of Hessian Comparison theorem ( Second question, John Lee, Introduction to Riemannian manifold ). Can anyone help?

Seems like you have to write what you explained informally. Define
$$A=\{t\in [0,b]:\gamma(t) \not\in U_0\}.$$
Notice that $b\in A$, as $\gamma(b)=q\not\in U_0$. So, $A$ is a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R},$ and hence exists $t^\prime:=\inf A$, an element of $\mathbb{R}$. By the properties of $\inf$, $t^\prime$ is a lower bound on $A$. Thus, if $z<t^\prime$ then $z\not\in A$. It then follows from the definition of $A$ that $\gamma\left(\left[0, t^{\prime}\right)\right) \subseteq U_0$.
Observe that $r$ is the composition of a diffeomorphism and a continuous map, which implies that $r$ is continuous. It follows that $A$ is the inverse image of a closed set, so it is closed. Hence, $t^\prime$ is an element in $A$. Assume by contradiction that $r(\gamma(t^\prime))> \pi R$. Then, by the intermediate value theorem exists $0<b<t^\prime$ such that $r(\gamma(b))=\pi R$. So $b\in A$, but then $t^\prime\ne \inf A$ a contradiction.

Thanks. And why $A$ is the inverse image of a closed set? Since $A = (r \circ \gamma)^{-1}([\pi R,  \infty))$?

What I had in mind when I wrote it: As $r$ is continuous, $U_0$ is open as the inverse image of the open subset $(-\infty,\pi R)$, and $A$ is by definition $\gamma^{-1}(U\backslash U_0)$; hence it is the inverse image of a closed subset. I guess what you wrote in the comment is equivalent

O.K. Thanks. I learned a lot.
